# Issues setting up react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, proxy

I am having issues setting up react even though I have both node and npm installed.

Typing in:

```
npx create-react-app new-test-react --use-npm
```

Results in the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fhelper-plugin-utils failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your_proxy_ip
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abhin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-03T06_40_10_273Z-debug.log
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks alot

Comment: It seems npm is trying to fetch a package (babel-helper-plugin-utils) and it does not seem to be able to find internet access.

Comment: @Orhan Unfortunately, I still get the same error afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are behind some proxy thats why you were not able to remote registry. The error clearly says so.

`network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fhelper-plugin-utils failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your_proxy_ip`

Set the proxy config properly with these commands

```
$ npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
$ npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
```

More info - https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/how-to-run-npm-behind-a-proxy-server-a-step-by-step-guide/19386

Comment: How do I find the username, password, proxy server url and port?